# Vue.js - How check all children component of parent component when will be mounted

Tags: vue.js, height, mount

i need to solve very deep  problem (for me) with check when are children components are ready in DOM (mounted).
Here is demo: https://playcode.io/1625516

Is there any easy way how to know when are all children or children of children mounted and at  root parent know that?

One choice is use ResizeObserver (seems to be OK) but im looking for some native way in Vue which I may have overlooked.

Thx.

Comment: Depends on the case, which is unknown. nextTick in onMounted is enough in general if children structure is static

Answer (score -2):

In Vue.js, you can use the `$nextTick` function to execute code after the component has been rendered in the DOM. This can be used to ensure that child components are mounted.
Here's an example of how you can modify your code to use `$nextTick` to detect when the child component is mounted:

```
  <template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="isMounted" style="height: 300px; background: limegreen">C2</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'C2',
  data() {
    return {
      isMounted: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.isMounted = true;
      console.log('C2 mounted');
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

In this modified version, the `isMounted` flag is set to true using `$nextTick`, which ensures that the DOM has been updated before the flag is updated. This can be used to determine if the component and its children are mounted.

Comment: This will not and cannot work. I deliberately set delayed rendering in child components.

I'm interested in how to find out in the root component and correctly, for example, calculate the height.

Did you see a demo?